# extract characters from text field

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Within Acrobat, using the action menu/ javascript editor, I'm trying to display each of the 17 characters of a string into 17 different text boxes.
If I define the var with functions substring or charAt I get functions not defined errors. If I just use the brackets as in my code below, my result box displays "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

```
var fullvin = this.getField("vinner");
var v1 = this.getField("vin1");
var v2 = this.getField("vin2");

v1.value=fullvin.value[1]
v2.value=fullvin.value[2]
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a "comb" with 17 characters. Acrobat has this functionality built in. Just create a text box and in the "options" tab, deselect the default check boxes for "scroll long text" and "check spelling, then check the "Comb of" radio button then add the number of characters you need.

Comment: Thank you, Joel, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Solved. thank you.